# Как найти точку координат в границах района?

Tags: php, sql, карты, координаты, геокодирование

Есть координаты точки: 60.574855 56.832531

Есть точки границ района записанные в SQL TEXT: 60.562904 56.842296,60.56303 56.8423,60.563293 56.84232,60.563438 56.842346,60.563764 56.842367,60.563913 56.842395,60.564083 56.842456,60.564213 56.842482,60.564395 56.842495,60.564586 56.842476

Как то возможно с помощью php/mysql найти точку в границах этого района?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ясно что  ничего не ясно. вы нам первую точку для чего написали? Проверить надо входит в район, или что?

Comment: Смотрите есть адрес, я с помощью геокодирования от Яндекса получаю его координаты, например: 60.574855 56.832531
Далее у меня в базе есть границы районов которые записаны в виде точек.
Цель узнать входит ли точка в границы одного из районов, районов разумеется много.

Comment: Преобразуете в геометрические объекты, и применяете что-то типа ST_Contains().

Comment: @Akina спасибо, не знал про ST_Contains, сейчас мельком глянул - кажется именно то что нужно, завтра буду пробовать, надеюсь разберусь!